# keras parametes for multilabel text classification

Tags: python-3.x, keras, text-classification, keras-layer

I am using keras in my multiclass text classifcation, the dataset contains 25000 arabic tweets with 10 class labels
I use this code :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(10902,)))#10902
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()
 #categorical_crossentropy
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',        optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
..
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=100,
                    epochs=30,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.5)
```

Summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 512)               5582336   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_22 (Activation)   (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_23 (Activation)   (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 10)                5130      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_24 (Activation)   (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,850,122
Trainable params: 5,850,122
Non-trainable params: 0
```

but i get error:
 *could not convert string to float: 'food'*
where food is a class name

when i change loss to categorical_crossentropy  i get the error
 *Error when checking target: expected activation_24 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)*

**Update**

```
'
nd=data.replace(['ads', 'Politic', 'eco', 'food', 'health', 'porno', 'religion', 'sports', 'tech','tv'], 
                     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10]) 
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(10902,10)))#no. of words
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.summary()
     #categorical_crossentropy
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',        optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    y_train=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train) 
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=100,
                        epochs=30,
                        verbose=1,
                        validation_split=0.5)'
```

Comment: you can't pass strings into a neural network.. consider using a one-hot-encoding to transform strings into numbers or use an embedding layer

Comment: you mean  i replace class name to a number ?

Answer (score 0):

You correctly used `Dense(10)` at the end, in order to produce ten results, one for each class.

But you should have your output `y_train` shaped also with 10 classes.

It should have shape `(numberOfTweets, 10)`.

For this you should:

- If you have an array with indices, transform them using the keras function `y_train=to_categorical(y_train)`.
- If you have them as strings, you must transform them in indices, and then use `to_categorical`

Comment: shape (numberOfTweets, 10).  contains number of tweets or number of words??
I change class label to integer
nd=data.replace(['ads', 'Politic', 'eco', 'food', 'health', 'porno', 'religion', 'sports', 'tech','tv'],  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10]) 
and add

y_train=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train) 

get error
 Error when checking input: expected dense_22_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (15058, 10902)

Comment: Please update your code, this error shows you're not using the same model you posted here.